# 'Se dire' vs. 'dire'

Tags: verbes, verbes-pronominaux

I recently received this sentence in an email, and I was unsure about the subtle difference between *dire* and *se dire*.

> Nous essayons de donner une vision fidèle de ce qui **s’est dit** durant le conseil.

My initial assumption is that *se dire* is roughly 'to be said' with a focus on the language actually being spoken whereas *dire* focuses the attention on the speaker. Is *avoir été dit* not proper French?

Comment: The passive voice is one of the many meanings the reflexive can have, and has here, as you thought.

Answer (score 4):

yes, you could translate

> ce qui s'est dit

by

> what have been said

you could also say

> ... une vision fidèle de ce qui a été dit ...

but beware, in some case "il s'est dit" = "he told himself"
"Il s'est dit que ce serait une bonne idée"
means
"He told himself it would be a great idea"

Comment: So, that is to say that in this case, there is no significant difference between *ce qui s'est dit* and *ce qui a été dit*? Does one feel more natural than the other, or is it simply a matter of preference?

Comment: I think it is simply a matter of preference. For me there is no difference between the 2 forms.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a difference in time-reference.   In "s'est dit" we have the present tense in the passive format, whereas in "a été dit" we have "passé composé" in the passive format.

Comment: *Il s'est dit* is not present in passive mode (that would be *Il est dit*)  but the verb *se dire* (*pronominal*) in *passé composé* tense.

Comment: Yes, the present in the passive mode should be "il se dit". I think that "il est dit" is not very common because 'se dire" is a "pronominal" verb.

Comment: That's not what's being questioned here. The question is about the difference between dire and se dire